# Sorting out Nodetypes after yield in Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have the follwoing query in cypher

```
Match(n1: Red)
Where n1.Id = "someId"
Call apoc.path.subgraphAll(n1,{ minLevel: 0,maxLevel: 100,relationshipFilter: "link",labelFilter: "+Red|Blue"})
Yield nodes, relationships
Return nodes, relationships
```

The graph I query has roughly a structure of "Red -> Blue -> Red" where all the edges are of the type "link".

The query yield exactly the expected result in the browser client.

My C# looks like this:

```
string subgraphAll = "apoc.path.subgraphAll";
object optionsObj = new {
                minLevel = 0,
                maxLevel = 100,
                relationshipFilter = $"{link}",
                labelFilter = $"+{Red}|{Blue}",
                beginSequenceAtStart = "true",
                bfs = true,
                filterStartNode = false,
                limit = -1,
                //endNodes = null,
                //terminatorNodes = null,
                //whitelistNodes = null,
                //blacklistNodes = null,
            };
 string options = JObject.FromObject(optionsObj).ToString();

 var query = client.Cypher
     .Match($"(n1:{"Red"})")
     .Where((Red n1) => n1.Id == "someId")
     .Call($"{subgraphAll}(n1, {options})")
     .Yield($"nodes,relationships")
     //FigureOut what to do
     .Return<Object>("");
     var result = query.ResultsAsync.Result;
```

My question is: How would I write that in C# with the Neo4J client and how do I get typesafe lists at the end (something like `List<Red>, List<Blue>, List<Relationship>`).
As Red and Blue are different types in C#, I don't see how I can deserialize the mixed "nodes" list from the query.

Note that my examples are a bit simplified. The Nodetypes are not strings but come from Enums in my application to have a safe way to know what node types exist and there are real models behind those types.

I tried to break out the whole parametrization of the stored proc, but the code is untested and I don't know if there is a better solution to do this yet. If there is a better way, please advise on that too.

I am new to cypher, so I need a little help here.

My idea was to split the nodes list into two lists (Red and Blue List) and then output the three Lists as properties of an anonymous object (as in the examples). Unfortunately My cypher isn't good enough to figure it out yet, and translating to the c# syntax at the same time doesn't help either.

My main concern is that once I deserialize into a list of untyped objects, It will be hell to parse them back into my models. So I want the query to do that sorting out for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you want to go down the route of parsing the outputs into `Red/Blue` classes, it's going to be easier to do it in `C#` than in `Cypher`.

Unfortunately, also in this case - I think it'll be easier to execute the query using the `Neo4j.Driver` driver instead of `Neo4jClient` - and that's because at the moment, `Neo4jClient` seems to remove the `id` (etc) properties you'd need to be able to rebuild the graph properly.

With `4.0.3` of the Client you can access the `Driver` by doing this:

```
((BoltGraphClient)client).Driver
```

I have used a 'Movie/Person' example, as it's a dataset I had to hand, but the principals are the same, something like:

```
var queryStr = @"
    Match(n1: Movie)
    Where n1.title = 'The Matrix'
    Call apoc.path.subgraphAll(n1,{ minLevel: 0,maxLevel: 2,relationshipFilter: 'ACTED_IN',labelFilter: '+Movie|Person'})
    Yield nodes, relationships
    Return nodes, relationships
";

var movies = new List<Movie>();
var people = new List<People>();

var session = client.Driver.AsyncSession();
var res = await session.RunAsync(queryStr);
await res.FetchAsync();
    
foreach (var node in res.Current.Values["nodes"].As<List<INode>>())
{
    //Assumption of one label per node.
    switch(node.Labels.Single().ToLowerInvariant()){
        case "movie":
            movies.Add(new Movie(node));
            break;
        case "person":
            /* similar to above */
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("node", node.Labels.Single(), "Unknown node type");
    }
}
```

With `Movie` etc defined as:

```
public class Movie {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    
    public Movie(){}
    public Movie(INode node){
        Id = node.Id;
        Title = node.Properties["title"].As<string>();
    }
}
```

The *not pulling back ids etc* problem for the client is something I need to look at how to fix, but this is the quickest way short of that to get where you want to be.